# Getting a specific key based on a condition in an inner dictionary - python

Tags: python

I have `records` dictionary as:

```
{0.001: {'num_iter': 8112, 'accuracy': 98.41827768014059}, 
 0.002: {'num_iter': 4255, 'accuracy': 98.41827768014059}, 
 0.003: {'num_iter': 2837, 'accuracy': 98.41827768014059}, 
 0.004: {'num_iter': 2128, 'accuracy': 98.41827768014059}, 
 0.005: {'num_iter': 1702, 'accuracy': 98.41827768014059}, 
 0.006: {'num_iter': 1417, 'accuracy': 98.41827768014059}, 
 0.007: {'num_iter': 4, 'accuracy': 63.620386643233736}, 
 0.008: {'num_iter': 4, 'accuracy': 62.741652021089635}, 
 0.009: {'num_iter': 3, 'accuracy': 52.196836555360285}}
```

All I want is to get the key with the highest `accuracy` and if there is more than one, then consider the one with the lowest `num_iter`. In this case it will be **`0.006`**.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a single maximum element, use `max`. It accepts a `key` parameter just like `sorted`, but runs in O(n) time instead of O(n log n), meaning it is more efficient.

```py
>>> max(d, key=lambda k: (d[k]['accuracy'], -d[k]['num_iter']))
0.006
```

Here, the keys are compared by a tuple of `(accuracy, -num_iter)` meaning it selects the key with the maximum `accuracy`, using the minimum `num_iter` as a tie-breaker.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the key parameter of [max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max):

```
data = {0.001: {'num_iter': 8112, 'accuracy': 98.41827768014059},
        0.002: {'num_iter': 4255, 'accuracy': 98.41827768014059},
        0.003: {'num_iter': 2837, 'accuracy': 98.41827768014059},
        0.004: {'num_iter': 2128, 'accuracy': 98.41827768014059},
        0.005: {'num_iter': 1702, 'accuracy': 98.41827768014059},
        0.006: {'num_iter': 1417, 'accuracy': 98.41827768014059},
        0.007: {'num_iter': 4, 'accuracy': 63.620386643233736},
        0.008: {'num_iter': 4, 'accuracy': 62.741652021089635},
        0.009: {'num_iter': 3, 'accuracy': 52.196836555360285}}

result = max(data, key=lambda x : (data[x]['accuracy'], -1 * data[x]['num_iter']))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
0.006
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sorted()` with custom `key=` parameter:

```
d = {0.001: {'num_iter': 8112, 'accuracy': 98.41827768014059},
 0.002: {'num_iter': 4255, 'accuracy': 98.41827768014059},
 0.003: {'num_iter': 2837, 'accuracy': 98.41827768014059},
 0.004: {'num_iter': 2128, 'accuracy': 98.41827768014059},
 0.005: {'num_iter': 1702, 'accuracy': 98.41827768014059},
 0.006: {'num_iter': 1417, 'accuracy': 98.41827768014059},
 0.007: {'num_iter': 4, 'accuracy': 63.620386643233736},
 0.008: {'num_iter': 4, 'accuracy': 62.741652021089635},
 0.009: {'num_iter': 3, 'accuracy': 52.196836555360285}}

print(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda k: (-k[1]['accuracy'], k[1]['num_iter']))[0][0])
```

Prints:

```
0.006
```

---

Note: If you want just one value - use `max()` function - complexity O(n) instead of O(nlogn) of `sorted()`

Comment: What does -k do?

Comment: @alex067 `-k[1]['accuracy']` negates the 'accuracy' value - that way we are sorting in reversed order - from highest accuracy to lowest.

Comment: This has a time complexity of O(n*logn)